# Names of columns from df - hovering tool - Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using Bokeh to plot some data and was wondering how could I add the names of the data that I am plotting in the hover tool.

I have the following:

```
A = df_1['Temp']
B = df_2['Voltage']
C = df_3['Pressure']
x = df[Time]

TOOLTIPS_1 = [
    ("Name", '@Name')
    ("Time", "$x s"),
    ("Temperature", "$y °C"),
]

p = figure(title="Box", 
            x_axis_label='Time [secs]', 
            y_axis_label='Temperature [°C]',  
            tooltips=TOOLTIPS_1)
```

I have different dfs for each observation. I think that my problem is that I should normalize everything into one df and from there take or make a Name array with the columns name.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

- Put all the different df data in one `ColumnDataSource` with a `"Name"` column, plot all that data with a single glyph call, and then reference `@Name` in the tooltips, or
- Make separate `ColumnDataSource` for each df, plot each using a separate glyph that gets an appropriate `name` parameter passed to it, then reference `$name` in the tooltips.

Information about special tooltip variables like `$name` is [in the documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#basic-tooltips).